# Change the default time zone of the app in swift

Tags: swift, timezone

I'm using picker view to select a new time zone and here I set a new default time zone for the app:

```
 if let local = selectedTimeZone {
     let timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: local)
     NSTimeZone.default = timeZone!
 }
```

here for example, `selectedTimeZone` is equal `"America/Chicago"`

And whenever this page get open, I read default value of time zone and show it as a selected time zone:

```
  if let index = timeZone.firstIndex(where: { $0.zoneName == NSTimeZone.default.identifier }) {
     pickerViewField.textField.text = timeZone[index].zoneName
  }
```

When a new time zone is selected, it seems work and in the app, the user can go around and when the user opens the setting, the picker view label shows the new time zone. 
But when I close the app completely and open it again, the time zone gets back the default time zone of the device, not the new one that selected in the app.

Now my question is; do I need to store the new value of the time zone somewhere and when the app gets open, I set the new value again in the first place? Or there is something wrong in my code?

Many thanks

Comment: You'll need to manually persist the time zone. The normal way to do this is to use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults)

Comment: I think about that, but it doesn't make sense :) when you set new timezone, it should be handled by iOS, am I right?

Comment: The time zone for your application is handled by the `Foundation` framework. It won't persist it between launches of the app unless you tell it to, much like any other configuration parameter.